# How do I create my own Classes/Objects in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, class

When I try to do this in an AS CDATA block, it tells me I can't have a class declared within a class (the MX:Application itself). Makes sense. But where and how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new file with a .as extension, and put your class definition in there.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to watch [the screencast](http://www.firststepsinflex.com/components_screencast.html) for the Components chapter of [First Steps in Flex](http://www.firststepsinflex.com).  It walks through how to do this.